# Rails controller redirect not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have code in a Rails controller:

```
  def addinvtimes
    @invoice = params[:invtimes][:invoice_id]
    if params[:event_ids] != nil
      params[:event_ids].each do |i|
        newinvtime = Invtime.new(
            linetype_id: 1,
            invoice_id: @invoice,
            event_id: i.to_i
        )
        if newinvtime.save
          format.html { redirect_to invoice_path(@invoice), :notice => 'Invoice Time was successfully added.' }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to invoice_path(@invoice), :notice => 'ERROR.' }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Why am I getting the error `too few arguments` here:

```
format.html { redirect_to invoice_path(@invoice), :notice => 'Invoice Time was successfully added.' }
```

In the console, I get

```
>> invoice_path(@invoice)
=> "/invoices/29"
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to wrap the `format.` portion in a `respond_to` block. Should look like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  if newinvtime.save
      format.html { redirect_to invoice_path(@invoice), :notice => 'Invoice Time was successfully added.' }
  else
      format.html { redirect_to invoice_path(@invoice), :notice => 'ERROR.' }
  end
end
```